# Format String using List of String as an argument in C#

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I'm having a List, it contains the Person's Information

C# Code:

```
List<string> Person = new List<string>() {"Watson", "1001", "Female"};
```

My Expected String should be

```
string format = @"Name: {0}({1}) - {2}";
string expectedString = string.Format(format, ......);
```

I wish to **`LOOP`** the `List<string> Person` as an argument within the method `string.Format()`

I need to format the string in dynamic not by index number (i.e., static).

The Output should be

```
string expectedString = "Name: Watson(1001) - Female";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `string.Format` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a params object array argument, if the list order is guaranteed.

```
List<string> Person = new List<string>() {"Watson", "1001", "Female"};
string format = @"Name: {0}({1}) - {2}";
string expectedString = string.Format(format, Person.ToArray());
```

This outputs `Name: Watson(1001) - Female`